# Integration of holomorhic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function in $D(o, \rho)$ and let $\gamma(t) = re^{it}$ with $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \le r \le \rho$ I want to compute 
$$I=\int_{\gamma} \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz $$

In the case where $|a| > r, |b| > r$

Now I know that $f$ is holomorphic but honestly I'm stuck. I know there aren't actual computations to make. And I don't know how to see if $(z-a)$ and $(z-b)$ are holomorphic

**EDIT**: I now know which tools to use to solve such an integral:

Since $\gamma$ is  closed path, if I show that $J=\dfrac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}$ is holomorphic, then there exists a primitive of J therefore $I=0$

**My problem** How do I show that J is holomorphic. I think If I show that $(z-a)$ and $(z-b)$ are holomorphic, I'm done (because I believe the multiplication and division of holomorphic function is a holomorphic function). Why is it that $(z-a)$ and $(z-b)$ are holomorphic when $a$ and $b$ are outside the circle of radius r?

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are outside the disk bounded by $\gamma$, then the integrand is holomorphic in this disk and so the integral is zero.

Comment: According to what property (I looked through my notes and didn't find such a property)?

Comment: Otherwise you can calculate residues

Comment: @SylvesterStallone, the Cauchy-Goursat theorem for instance.

Comment: @Ihf Thank you, why is the integrand holomorphic if a and b are outside of the disk?